# Error in Implementation Cross Validation in KNN Python

Tags: python, anaconda, cross-validation, knn

I learned python KNN from scratch from this: https://machinelearningmastery.com/tutorial-to-implement-k-nearest-neighbors-in-python-from-scratch/
I want to implement Cross Validation from this:
https://machinelearningmastery.com/implement-backpropagation-algorithm-scratch-python/
Here is my implementation:

```
#Input
file = 'wdbc.csv'
fitur = 30
k = 2
n_folds = 2
#split = 0.80
#Proses
dataset = loadDataset(file, fitur, trainingSet, testSet)
folds = cross_validation_split(dataset, n_folds)
for fold in folds:
    trainingSet = list(folds)
    trainingSet.remove(fold)
    trainingSet = sum(trainingSet, [])
    #print(trainingSet)
    testSet = list()
    predictions = []
    for row in fold:
        row_copy = list(row)
        testSet.append(row_copy)
        #row_copy[-1] = None
    for x in range(len(testSet)):
        neighbors = getNeighbors(trainingSet, testSet[x], k)
        result = getResponse(neighbors)
        predictions.append(result)
```

But it's output has error:

```
File "C:/Users/user.compaq/Documents/help/cobaknn_crossval.py", line 45, in euclideanDistance
    distance += math.pow((instance1[x] - instance2[x]), 2)

TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for -: 'str' and 'float'
```

How can I fix this? All the instance1[x] and instance2[x] I've guaranteed them as float, but I don't know how the program identify one of them is string.
Help me. Thankyou.

Comment: I've seen this code before for loading the dataset. Are you sure you want to pass `fitur` instead of `split` into that function?

Comment: Also, what is `trainingSet = sum(trainingSet, [])` supposed to accomplish? That will error out trying to concat a list to an int

Comment: the split has done with k-fold cross validation